# How do I attach file along with body using Mail::send?

Tags: perl, email

This is code I tried from different sources, after I googled. I was not able to add body to mail or attachment is missing. I cannot have both of them simultaneously.

```
my $boundary = '==' . time . '==';
my $msg = new Mail::Send;
$msg->to($to);
$msg->add('From',$from);
$msg->subject($subject);
$msg->add('Content-Type', qq(multipart/mixed; boundary="$boundary";));

my $fh = $msg->open;
print $fh "--$boundary\n";

if(defined($body)) {

    print $fh "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1;\n";
    print $fh "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable;\n";
    print $fh "This is the body content : ".$body;
    print $fh $body;
    print $fh "--$boundary\n";
}
if(defined($filename) && defined($type) && defined($data)) {

    print $fh "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename;\n";
    print $fh "Content-Type: $type; name=$filename; charset=iso-8859-1;\n";
    print $fh "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit;\n\n";
    print $fh "--$boundary\n";
}
    $fh->close or LOGDIE "couldn't send email: $!\n";
```

Comment: Save some time and energy => http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.030/lib/MIME/Lite.pm#SYNOPSIS

Comment: [This link has examples using various modules, including Mail::Send](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=19430).

Comment: @codnodder I have seen the link.

Answer (score 1):

The major flaw is, that while you check for $data you don't add $data after you wrote the MIME-Header, e.g. a "print $fh $data" before the final boundary is missing. But there are more flaws:

- the last MIME part must end with --$boundary--, not just --$boundary
- Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit might work, but will not work with all mail servers. It would be better to use Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 and then use MIME::Base64 to encode the binary
- the semicolons at the end of the MIME-Headers are wrong. Semicolons are only used to separate parts inside a MIME-Header.
- the specification of charset is only needed if type is text/plain, but it should not do harm in other cases. But it will do harm if your text/plain part is not encoded in latin1 but utf-8 or other encodings.

Unless you really know how MIME works (which does not seem to be the case) it would be much easier to use MIME::Lite or MIME::Tools to handle all these details right.

Comment: I tried as you said but no get through. It would be nice if you share piece of code which is functional.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `use Mime::Lite;
my $m = Mime::Lite->new(...);
$m->attach(...);
print $m->as_string`

for more details: http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.030/lib/MIME/Lite.pm